# Tag Categories Report

Tags: reporting

I am trying to make more Fields available in the Tag Categories report. I would like to pull in fields from the related Client record. Right now, under the 'Topics' object, I am able to select the Client Name, but that is all.

Does anyone know if this is possible to configure?

I also tried recreating this in a custom report type and adding the fields via a lookup relationship but was unable to.

[image]